# finding equation of plane thru point $(2,0,1)$ and perpendicular to line $x=3t$, $y=2-t$, $z=3 + 4t$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have an exam tomorrow and I don't understand how my professor found the solution to this problem when every other solution to this problem I have found did it a different way. The other solutions to this problem have used $<3,-1,4>$ as the normal vector to the plane, but my professor first found two vectors perpendicular to the line $<1,3,0>$ and $<0,4,1>$, then used the starting point $(2,0,1)$ and the perpendicular vectors of the line to find two parallel vectors of the plane $<3,3,1>$ and $<2,4,2>$. She then used the cross product of the two parallel vectors of the plane to find the normal vector of the plane which she found to be $<2,-4,6>$. Her answer came out to be $2x-4y+6z=10$ whereas every other solution I have found just was $3x-y+4z=10$. Which method is correct?

Comment: Your method and result are correct. $(3,3,1)$ and $(2,4,2)$ are not parallel vectors of the plane. They are points of the plane, as can be seen from the way they were constructed, or from the fact that they are solutions of your equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

No need for cross product to find a normal because you are already given $<3,-1,4>$.  The way to think of this is that points in the plane $(x,y,z)$ determine vectors $<x-2,y,z-1>$ since you are given that $(2,0,1)$ lies in the plane. Since those vectors and the normal have to dot product to $0$ that leads to:

$3(x-2) - y + 4(z-1) = 0$

which becomes your final equation.